# how to use SharePoint 2010 web-part - after deployed?

Tags: web-part, deployment

i execute this command on power shell

```
Add-SPSolution C:\Deployment\MyFristWebPart.wsp
```

after execute i get this result:

```
Name                           SolutionId                           Deployed
----                           ----------                           --------
MyFristWebPart.wsp             de016dbb-4273-4b79-88cb-52b3aebcb335  False
```

after that i execute this command:

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity MyFristWebPart.wsp -WebApplication  http://sp2010 -GACDeployment
```

after i done with the above.

i went to SP Central Administration

`click on System Settings>>Farm Management >> Manage farm solutions>>>` there i see the my webpart

```
Name: MyFirstWebPart.wsp
Status Deployed 
To: http://sp2010
```

my question is how do i use this webpart in my sp 2010 page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the solution is on the farm and installed, you need to enable the feature on the site collection.  Go to your site collection site settings and click the Site Collection Features link under the Site Collection Administration area. The name of your feature will be listed there.  Click the activate button.  The page will refresh and the status of Activated will appear to the right of the button, which now reads Deactivate.

Now you have to add the webpart on the page.  Go to the page where you want to display this webpart.  Under the Site Actions, select Edit Page.  In the zone where you want to display the webpart, click the "add a webpart' link.  The ribbon at the top will show the list of available webparts.  By default, your webpart will be in the Custom folder.  Click this folder and the list of webparts in this folder will display in the window to the right.  Click the add button to add the webpart to your page.  Save the changes by clicking the Save and Exit button under the page section of the ribbon.